# run time exceeded on all test cases : Ideas how to optimize this code?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, time, runtime

It runs fine for small sets of input, but with very large input it runs more than one second. Looking for ideas to optimize execution time. This is a codesignal challenge, I already submitted, but could not optimize and still curious.

Any ideas are appreciated to help optimize this code; Seems most things I've tried have affected the results, so here is the clean code that works.

Here is the description:
You've created a new programming language, and now you've decided to add hashmap support to it. Actually you are quite disappointed that in common programming languages it's impossible to add a number to all hashmap keys, or all its values. So you've decided to take matters into your own hands and implement your own hashmap in your new language that has the following operations:
•   insert x y - insert an object with key x and value y.
•   get x - return the value of an object with key x.
•   addToKey x - add x to all keys in map.
•   addToValue y - add y to all values in map.
To test out your new hashmap, you have a list of queries in the form of two arrays: queryTypes contains the names of the methods to be called (eg: insert, get, etc), and queries contains the arguments for those methods (the x and y values).
Your task is to implement this hashmap, apply the given queries, and to find the sum of all the results for get operations.

```
    #For queryType = ["insert", "insert", "addToValue", "addToKey", "get"] 
    #and query = [[1, 2], [2, 3],     [2], [1], [3]], the output should be solution
    #(queryType, query) = 5.
    #The hashmap looks like this after each query:
    #1 query: {1: 2}
    #2 query: {1: 2, 2: 3}
    #3 query: {1: 4, 2: 5}
    #4 query: {2: 4, 3: 5}
    #5 query: answer is 5
    from collections import defaultdict

    def solution(queryType, query):
    hashmap = defaultdict(int)
    results = []
    updated_keys = set()

    def insert(key, value):
        hashmap[key] = value

    def get(key):
        results.append(hashmap[key])

    def add_to_key(val):
        updated_dict = {}
        for key, value in hashmap.items():
            updated_key = key + val
            updated_dict[updated_key] = value
        hashmap.clear()
        hashmap.update(updated_dict)

    def add_to_value(val):
        nonlocal hashmap
        hashmap = {k: v + val for k, v in hashmap.items()}

    for i in range(len(queryType)):
        op = queryType[i]
        q = query[i]

        if op == "insert":
            insert(*q)
        elif op == "get":
            get(q[0])
        elif op == "addToKey":
            add_to_key(q[0])
        elif op == "addToValue":
            add_to_value(q[0])

    return sum(results)
```

Comment: Does SHOUTING help explain?

Comment: No, apologize for that. First time posting.  I was trying to get it to accept the text.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use kind of cumulative algorithm. Where you actually not adding anything both to keys and to values and store it in the variables like `cumulative_k` and `cumulative_v`. The algorithm that passes tests:

```
def solution(queryType, query):
    ret_val = 0
    map_ = {}
    cumulative_k = 0
    cumulative_v = 0
    
    for idx, operation in enumerate(queryType):

    args = query[idx]
    
    if operation == "insert":
        key, val = args[0], args[1]
        map_[key - cumulative_k] = val - cumulative_v
    elif operation == "addToValue":
        cumulative_v += args[0]
    elif operation == "addToKey":
        cumulative_k += args[0]
    else:  # get: only get alters the answer
        key = args[0]
        key -= cumulative_k
        val = map_[key] + cumulative_v
        ret_val += val
return ret_val
```